# When I use the play command on my discord bot nothing happens

Tags: discord, discord.py

I am new to using discord.py but have experience using python. I am currently working on a discord music bot using discord.py and when I use the command "*play (song name)" nothing happens even though the bot is in the VC. I want the bot to be able to search youtube for the user's request and play it like any other music bot on discord like Rythum or Groovy. Any other suggestions you have for the code would be greatly appreciated as well. Thanks!

here is my code:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
import youtube_dl
import asyncio
from random import choice

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='*')
queue=[]
status = '18 Naked Cowboys'

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Rancher is online!")

    await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching,name=status))
@client.command(name='ping',help='This command will show that my ping is superior than yours!')
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f'**Pong!** Latency: {round(client.latency * 1000)}ms')

@client.command(name='hello',help='This command returns a random the welcome message!')
async def hello(ctx):
    responses = ['***grumble*** Why you wake me up?!','Penis']
    await ctx.send(choice(responses))

    youtube_dl.utils.bug_reports_message = lambda: ''

ytdl_format_options = {
    'format': 'bestaudio/best',
    'outtmpl': '%(extractor)s-%(id)s-%(title)s.%(ext)s',
    'restrictfilenames': True,
    'noplaylist': True,
    'nocheckcertificate': True,
    'ignoreerrors': False,
    'logtostderr': False,
    'quiet': True,
    'no_warnings': True,
    'default_search': 'auto',
    'source_address': '0.0.0.0' # bind to ipv4 since ipv6 addresses cause issues sometimes
}

ffmpeg_options = {
    'options': '-vn'
}

ytdl = youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ytdl_format_options)

class YTDLSource(discord.PCMVolumeTransformer):
    def __init__(self, source, *, data, volume=0.5):
        super().__init__(source, volume)

        self.data = data

        self.title = data.get('title')
        self.url = data.get('url')
    @classmethod
    async def from_url(cls, url, *, loop=None, stream=False):
        loop = loop or asyncio.get_event_loop()
        data = await loop.run_in_executor(None, lambda: ytdl.extract_info(url, download=not stream))

        if 'entries' in data:
            # take first item from a playlist
            data = data['entries'][0]

        filename = data['url'] if stream else ytdl.prepare_filename(data)
        return cls(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(filename, **ffmpeg_options), data=data)
        
@client.command(name='join', help='This command makes the bot join the voice channel')
async def join(ctx):
    if not ctx.message.author.voice:
        await ctx.send("You are not connected to a voice channel")
        return
    
    else:
        channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel

    await channel.connect()

@client.command(name='queue', help='This command adds a song to the queue')
async def queue_(ctx, url):
    global queue

    queue.append(url)
    await ctx.send(f'`{url}` added to queue!')

@client.command(name='remove', help='This command removes an item from the list')
async def remove(ctx, number):
    global queue

    try:
        del(queue[int(number)])
        await ctx.send(f'Your queue is now `{queue}!`')
    
    except:
        await ctx.send('Your queue is either **empty** or the index is **out of range**')
        
@client.command(name='play', help='This command plays songs')
async def play(ctx):
    global queue

    server = ctx.message.guild
    voice_channel = server.voice_client

    async with ctx.typing():
        player = await YTDLSource.from_url(queue[0], loop=client.loop)
        voice_channel.play(player, after=lambda e: print('Player error: %s' % e) if e else None)

    await ctx.send('**Now playing:** {}'.format(player.title))
    del(queue[0])

@client.command(name='pause', help='This command pauses the song')
async def pause(ctx):
    server = ctx.message.guild
    voice_channel = server.voice_client

    voice_channel.pause()

@client.command(name='resume', help='This command resumes the song!')
async def resume(ctx):
    server = ctx.message.guild
    voice_channel = server.voice_client

    voice_channel.resume()

@client.command(name='view', help='This command shows the queue')
async def view(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f'Your queue is now `{queue}!`')

@client.command(name='leave', help='This command stops makes the bot leave the voice channel')
async def leave(ctx):
    voice_client = ctx.message.guild.voice_client
    await voice_client.disconnect()

@client.command(name='stop', help='This command stops the song!')
async def stop(ctx):
    server = ctx.message.guild
    voice_channel = server.voice_client

    voice_channel.stop()

client.run('')
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't assign anything to queue list. So you might need to modify play function a bit and append the url from user input to your queue. Here is an example of what the user will input `*play https://youtube.com/watch?v=abcdefghij`. And here's the code:

```
@client.command(name='play', help='This command plays songs')
async def play(ctx, *, search_url):
    global queue
    queue.append(search_url)
    server = ctx.message.guild
    voice_channel = server.voice_client

    async with ctx.typing():
        player = await YTDLSource.from_url(queue[0], loop=client.loop)
        voice_channel.play(player, after=lambda e: print('Player error: %s' % e) if e else None)

    await ctx.send('**Now playing:** {}'.format(player.title))
    del(queue[0])
```